# Why does setting session variable in Snowflake stored procedure not work?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

When I set a session variable as caller in a Snowflake stored procedure, the procedure throws error "Error: Session variable '$T' does not exist (line 5)"

This is how I defined my procedure :

```
create or replace procedure test()
returns varchar()
language SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$

begin
    set T = 0;
    select $T;
    return 'Done !';
    end;
    
$$;

call test();
```

If I set the variable T before running the procedure it works, but if I don't I get the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal because when the script is compiled, there is no session variable.  To be able to compile the snowflake script successfully, the session variable should exist.

Here is a workaround:

```
create or replace procedure test()
returns varchar()
language SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$
begin
    set T = 0;
    select getvariable('T');
    return 'Done !';
    end;
    
$$
;

    
call test();
```

Comment: But I am setting the session variable in the procedure, so it should exist when executing, right?

Comment: But it doesn't exist in the compilation time, right?

Comment: And as you can define variables in Snowflake Scripting, why do you need to define and use a session variable?

Comment: Anyway, I provided a workaround. @mel1

Comment: how do you actually select and return results from an actual query..as opposed to a simple value like 'Done!'?